# Laravel - Sending data to pivot table using a checkbox

Tags: php, html, database, laravel, checkbox

I have 3 tables : `projects` - `users` - `project_user`.

This is a `ManyOnMany` relation so that's why I have a pivot table.

I got them linked via my model using `belongsToMany`.

Now comes my problem.

I have a table like this: [image]

So I have a `project` selected, and a table with my `users` with `active/contribute` checkboxes. 
When the `active/contribute` checkbox is checked the user will be linked to the project.

So in my head I have something like this:

*When the `checkbox` is checked, it needs to send the `user_id` including the `$this->project_id`to the pivot table `project_user` so it will link the project <->user.*

But now the problem is that I have no clue how I'm going to get this into working code.

**HTML/Blade:**

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<tr>
    <td>
        {{$user->firstname}} {{$user->middlename}} {{$user->lastname}}
    </td>

    <td>
        <input name='contribute' type='hidden' value='0'>
            {!! Form::checkbox('', '1', false) !!}
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

**Model:**

User

```
public function projects() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project', 'project_user', 'user_id', 'project_id');
}
```

Project

```
public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'project_user', 'project_id', 'user_id');
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function edit($id, Project $project)
{
    $users = User::all();

    $project = $this->project->find($id);

    return view('project.edit', ['project' => $project, 'id' => 'edit'], compact('users'));
}

public function update(CreateProjectRequest $request, $project)
{
    $project = $this->project->find($project);
    $project->fill($request->input())->save();

    return redirect('project');
}
```

*Tell me if any other code is needed to be provided*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Input arrays like below, but you have to check if this user is already associated with this project.

```
{!! Form::checkbox('contribute['.$user->id.']', '1', $checkifinproject) !!}
```

Then use `sync` when you are updating in your Controller.
But before that, because you want only the `ids` with value 1 from the checkboxes, you have to filter out the zero values, then keep only the keys of the array `$request->input('users')`.

```
 $project = $this->project->find($project);
 $project->sync($prepared_ids);
```

Sync will then delete all the previous user_ids, associated with this project, from the table and save the new ones.

Comment: `if($request->get('contribute'))
        {
            foreach($request->get('contribute') as $k => $contribute)
            {
                if($contribute == 1)
                {
                    $project = $this->project->find($request->project_id);
                    $project->users()->attach($k);
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: , `<input name="contribute[{{$user->id}}]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>` , this is what I have right now, it will add to the table but it will keep adding to the table and it wont show it is already added

Comment: yes, it will get added to the database as long as I keep hitting "edit" a new rule will be added, example:  ( `id = 1 , project_id = 5, user_id = 1 `), ( `id = 1 , project_id = 5, user_id = 2 `) and so forth

Comment: Ok then the only thing is that you have to check if this user is in this project  then if true add `checked` attribute to the checkbox

Comment: What is a viable/effective way to do that? I'm so stuck up with this problem for so long I can't think straight about it atm

Comment: You have to check somehow all users against the users associated with this project and add if true a key checked true else false and then on add in your checkbox `$user["checked"] == true ? 'checked' : ''`

Comment: @Synyster did you manage to make it work? One thing if you use `attach` instead of `sync` you have to also `detach` the ones that are not selected.

Comment: Not yet. I'm stuck with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353788/laravel-sync-method-only-sending-the-2nd-data