# Laravel Sync method only sending the 2nd data

Tags: php, laravel

This piece of code should be deleting all old data from the database and when add the new ones (using sync())

Now I have a project with users, and a user can be linked to a project with a checkbox.

So on checkbox checked this function will trigger, but for example when I say that `user 1`  and `user 2` are going through this fuction to get added to the `pivot table` it will only send `user 2`, and `user 1` will not get through, what is going wrong?

And when I add 3 users `user 1`, `user 2`, `user 3`, only `user 2` will get added.

Controller

```
public function update(CreateProjectRequest $request)
{
    if($request->get('contribute'))
    {
        foreach($request->get('contribute') as $k => $contribute)
        {
            if($contribute == 1)
            {
                $project = $this->project->find($request->project_id);
                $project->users()->sync(array($k));

            }
        }
    }

    $project = $this->project->find($request->project_id);
    $project->fill($request->input())->save();

    return redirect('project');
}
```

Blade

```
@foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{$user->firstname}} {{$user->middlename}} {{$user->lastname}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {!! Form::checkbox('contribute['.$user->id.']', '1', $user->projects->contains('id', $project->id)) !!}
                </td>
            </tr>
@endforeach
```

On a  `dd($request->input());` at the start of my update method (with selecting atleast 3 users) this will get in return:

```
  array:9 [▼
  "_method" => "PATCH"
  "_token" => "0uIZNn6zwZjVKfgE0ckhDULeYda0OaLzKVdUgoM8"
  "name" => "Dire Straits"
  "completion_date" => "2015-05-18"
  "DataTables_Table_0_length" => "10"
  "contribute" => array:3 [▼
    1 => "1"
    3 => "1"
    2 => "1"
  ]
  "completed" => "1"
  "active" => "0"
  "project_id" => "11"
]
```

So `1 / 3 / 2` would be the `user_id` and `=> 1` should be the value.

Comment: have you debugged so far?

Comment: yes, if I put a dd($request->input()); at the start of my update method it will return: http://i.gyazo.com/f62f6de596a66e4eb0c55fba0e46ffcb.png , that should be actually right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `sync` gets called in `loop` 3 times so each time it's syncing one value. You have to pass an array of the ids in `sync` ex:

```
$project->users()->sync([1,3,2]);
```

Or if you want you can use `attach` when `contribute==1` and `detach` when `contribute==0`

Or if `contribute` doesnt return input when a user is deselected and it only returns when it is selected then you can try:

```
$this->project->users()->sync(array_keys($request->get('contribute'));
```

I just noticed that you have another bug unless you are updating many projects with one call you should put the line below on the first line of your function.

```
$project = $this->project->find($request->project_id);
```